# apt-get autoremove removes everything

Tags: apt

I'm running 13.10. I removed emacs, and then ran sudo apt-get autoremove, but it decided that it needed to remove all of these other things (a lot of which I probably need). Here is the full list:

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  ghc ghc-haddock latex-cjk-common libbsd-dev libffi-dev libgail-3-doc
  libgail-doc libgda-5.0-4 libgda-5.0-common libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-doc libgdl-3-5 libgdl-3-common libghc-data-default-doc
  libghc-dlist-dev libghc-dlist-doc libghc-mtl-doc libghc-transformers-doc
  libghc-x11-doc libghc-x11-xft-doc libgladeui-2-4 libgladeui-common
  libglib2.0-dev libglib2.0-doc libgmp-dev libgmpxx4ldbl libgstreamer1.0-dev
  libgtk-3-doc libgtk2.0-doc libgtksourceview-3.0-doc libharfbuzz-dev
  libid3tag0 libimlib2 libintl-perl libio-stringy-perl libipc-signal-perl
  libjson-perl liblockdev1 libmime-types-perl libnotify-doc libopts25-dev
  libpango1.0-doc libpcre3-dev libpcrecpp0 libpng12-dev libproc-waitstat-perl
  librecode0 libregexp-assemble-perl libremctl1 libreoffice-report-builder-bin
  libsource-highlight-common libsp1c2 libstdc++5 libtelepathy-glib-doc
  libtext-unidecode-perl libtie-ixhash-perl libvala-0.20-0 libwayland-dev
  libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-shm0-dev libxkbcommon-dev libxml-libxml-perl
  libxml-namespacesupport-perl libxml-parser-perl libxml-sax-base-perl
  libxml-sax-expat-perl libxml-sax-perl libxml2-dev libxml2-doc libxml2-utils
  m-tx manpages-posix manpages-posix-dev mercurial mercurial-common
  mime-construct moreutils musixtex openbsd-inetd pfb2t1c2pfb
  pidgin-encryption plt-scheme pmx policykit-1-doc python-bzrlib
  python-compizconfig python-configobj python-debianbts python-fpconst
  python-keyring python-launchpadlib python-lazr.restfulclient python-lazr.uri
  python-oauth python-reportbug python-scour python-secretstorage
  python-simplejson python-soappy python-wadllib python3-decorator
  python3-magic python3-simplegeneric quilt racket racket-common racket-doc
  remctl-client reportbug schroot-common screen sgml-data sp suckless-tools
  swath tex4ht tex4ht-common texinfo texlive-bibtex-extra
  texlive-fonts-extra-doc texlive-formats-extra texlive-games
  texlive-generic-extra texlive-humanities texlive-humanities-doc
  texlive-lang-african texlive-lang-cjk texlive-lang-cyrillic
  texlive-lang-czechslovak texlive-lang-english texlive-lang-european
  texlive-lang-french texlive-lang-german texlive-lang-indic
  texlive-lang-italian texlive-lang-other texlive-lang-polish
  texlive-lang-portuguese texlive-lang-spanish texlive-math-extra
  texlive-music texlive-omega texlive-plain-extra texlive-publishers
  texlive-publishers-doc texlive-science texlive-science-doc texlive-xetex
  tree valac-0.20 valac-0.20-vapi wmbubble wmbutton wmcalclock wmhdplop
  wmmemload wmnd wmweather xfonts-x3270-misc xmonad xsltproc
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
```

I tried installing and removing emacs again, but still it insists I remove all of these. libreoffice and python-twisted used to be on here until I set them to manual install. Why does Ubuntu want to remove all of these?

Comment: I think apt-get thinks you don't need this packages any more... (I think so, too) don't deceive yourself with the number of packages, a lot of them are just different "support" packages for applications. I would just trust in apt's work and remove them. You can reinstall it whenever you want. Which do you think you still need?

Comment: Most probably you removed metapackage holding these. Not practical solution in this case, but if you want to keep some random package installed as dependency, just run `apt-get install name_of_that_package`, and `autoremove` won't remove it anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any package of that you believe you need it just do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install package-you-need
```

That way you mark packages as manual and then you can do autoremove.

Answer (score 1):

No worries, you don't need them,

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

*Autoremove is used to remove packages that were automatically installed to satisfy dependencies for some package and that are no more needed*